# how to convert characterIsMember objective c to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have one part code objective c code and I want to convert to swift :

```
NSString *rawStr = [[tokenField textField] text];
        for (int i = 0; i < [rawStr length]; i++)
        {
            if (![charSet characterIsMember:[rawStr characterAtIndex:i]])
            {
                [recipient appendFormat:@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [rawStr characterAtIndex:i]]];
            }
        }
        if ([rawStr length])
        {
            [tokenField addTokenWithTitle:rawStr representedObject:recipient];
        }
```

please guide me about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using `NSString` the port is straight forward:

```
    let rawStr:NSString = tokenField.textField.text
    for i in 0..<rawStr.length {
        let currentChar = rawStr.characterAtIndex(i)
        if !charSet.characterIsMember(currentChar) {
            recipient.appendFormat("%@", NSString(format:"%c", currentChar))
        }
    }
    if rawStr.length > 0 {
        tokenField.addTokenWithTitle(rawStr, representedObject:recipient)
    }
```

Else the `String` class does not have a length method. You'll have to use `s.startIndex.advancedBy` syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are trying to keep characters that are not in your character set.

```
func strRemoveCharsNotInSet(str: String) -> String {
    let charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ".@")

    let temp = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charSet)
    let backToString = temp.joinWithSeparator("")

    return backToString
}

print(strRemoveChars("Hello@There.Friend"))

outputs:
    HelloThereFriend
```

Comment: If you down vote, at least comment why.